# Further code running before SWT modal shell is disposed

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

First off, I am pretty brand new to SWT (very used to Swing but trying to branch out to different tooling and wanted a more native look and feel for my application). Apologies if I'm asking obvious questions.

So, in my SWT application, I'm writing a base form (a `Shell`) that has a table with data from a database.

The `Edit` button on this form pops up another, modal `Shell`, that contains the data from the selected table row, and allows the user to edit the data and save it.

Code that launches the Edit Form:

```
EditForm frm = new EditForm(this, ...); // (other custom parameters specific to my application)
// should only run AFTER the form is disposed
refresh();
```

The `refresh()` method clears all rows from the table and re-populates it with updated data from the database.

The problem is, the `refresh()` method is running as soon as the `EditForm` is displayed. This tells me it's behaving asynchronously.

The `EditForm` is definitely modal:

```
public class EditForm extends Shell {
    public EditForm(Shell parent, ...) {
        super(Display.getCurrent(), SWT.TRIM | SWT.APPLICATION_MODAL);
    }
}
```

Do SWT `Shell` objects normally behave asynchronously like this, even if they are modal? Is there a way to "force" it to be synchronous, such that `refresh()` is called only when the `EditForm` is disposed?

Comment: All SWT widgets, including Shell, are not meant to be subclassed (see the JavaDoc). I recommend reworking your code accordingly.

Comment: Also, there is likely a mistake in which super constructor you call. I assume you want `super( parent, ... )` instead of `super( Display.getCurrent(), ... )`.

Comment: Huh, that's odd. I chose to create a new Shell from the File > New > Other menu, and it generated that class header (`extends Shell`) automatically. I have seen that note about not subclassing in other classes, but don't remember seeing it specifically in `Shell`. Weird. EDIT: I wonder why they didn't just make those classes `final` if they weren't meant to be subclassed. SWT is a nice concept but it feels like a very broken/underdeveloped API, especially when it comes to cross-platform behavior.

Comment: Making classes `final` is a very hard way of sway 'don't subclass this'. SWT has deliberately opted against `final` to allow subclassing as a last resort. E.g. you may be able to work around a bug by overriding a certain method. It is, of course, unfortunate for a UI design tool to violate a basic rule of the toolkit it generates code for.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what places do you feel broken/underdeveloped?

Comment: I think for the most part, it's stable, because I know of applications that are written in it, but the designer feels very clunky and programs written in it only seems to work best on Windows. With other platforms, it seems to have quite a few behavior issues. That said, if you want a true native feel to your application, it's always been recommended to use the development tools and SDK's for that specific platform anyways.

Comment: I am used to writing SWT UIs manually. Once you are familiar with the API, it is as fast as using a designer and leads to more readable code. When SWT development was at its peak, Windows was the dominant platform. That has led to a slight incline regarding stability and attention to detail on the other platforms. I agree, that for a true native feel it's usually best to use the native tools and libraries - but that, of course, comes at the price of re-doing the work for each platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a nested read-and-dispatch loop. If that is placed after the shell is opened, and the exit condition of the loop is 'shell is still open', then the refresh code will only be run after the nested shell was closed.

For example:

```
while ( !nestedShell.isDisposed() ) {
  if ( !display.readAndDispatch() )  {
    display.sleep();
  }
}
```

JFace is a library that offers utilities and thin abstractions over SWT. To build modal dialogs, if offers the `Dialog` class and its subclasses that have a `setBlockOnOpen()` method to control blocking behavior. Unfortunately, it drags in two or so other libraries, but it way be with considering.

Comment: OK, thanks for the info. I'm resorting to using the native development languages/libraries (e.g., .NET on Windows, Xcode on Mac), but I will keep this in mind if I ever go back to SWT.